# QV circuits fail to execute in real devices

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, quantum-volume

I tried to change a little the code [here](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/measuring-quantum-volume.html) for running the quantum volume circuits in real devices. My code is

```
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_bogota')

shots = 1000
for trial in range(ntrials):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    t_qcs = transpile(qv_circs[trial], backend=backend, initial_layout=qubit_lists[0])
    qobj = [assemble(t_qcs)]

    job_manager = IBMQJobManager()
    job_set_foo = job_manager.run(qobj, backend=backend, shots=shots, name='QV trial %d'%(trial))
print(job_set_foo.report(detailed=True))
print(f'Completed trial {trial+1}/{ntrials}')
```

But I get

```
status: job submit failed: 'bad input to assemble() function; must be either circuits or schedules'
```

I don't understand how this can fail,since `qv_circs` must contain the necessary attributes. Note that I wrote `qobj = [assemble(t_qcs)]` instead of `qobj = assemble(t_qcs)`. If I do the latter I obtain

```
'QasmQobj' object is not iterable
```

---

EDIT:

Some information about the objects:

```
print(t_qcs)
[<qiskit.circuit.quantumcircuit.QuantumCircuit object at 0x7fa2398698a0>]
print(type(t_qcs))
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: I'm having trouble recreating the issue, could you provide some more information on the `qv_circs` or `print(t_qcs)` / `print(type(t_qcs))` on the iteration that's failing?

Comment: Thanks! I added the prints you suggested, though I don't know exactly what should I look for in `qv_circs` (i.e. I don't know which methods you suggest to use to extract certain information). Meanwhile, I can tell you that I obtained the object using the qiskit tutorial: `import qiskit.ignis.verification.quantum_volume as qv` and `qv_circs, qv_circs_nomeas = qv.qv_circuits(qubit_lists, ntrials)` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Qiskit's release notes, under "IBM Q Provider 0.12.0"<sup>[[1]](https://qiskit.org/documentation/release_notes.html#ibm-q-provider-0-12-0)</sup>

> `qiskit.providers.ibmq.IBMQBackend.run()` method now takes one or more `QuantumCircuit` or `Schedule`. Use of `QasmQobj` and `PulseQobj` is now deprecated.

So, you shouldn't call `assemble`. Just pass the transpiled circuits to `IBMQJobManager.run()` method:

```
shots = 1000
for trial in range(ntrials):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    t_qcs = transpile(qv_circs[trial], backend=backend, initial_layout=qubit_lists)

    job_manager = IBMQJobManager()
    job_set_foo = job_manager.run(t_qcs, backend=backend, shots=shots, name='QV trial %d'%(trial))
    
print(job_set_foo.report(detailed=True))
print(f'Completed trial {trial+1}/{ntrials}')
```

I tested this code using the latest Qiskit version and it worked without any problem. The backend was `ibmq_santiago` (it is the backend returned by [`least_busy()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.least_busy.html) function when I called it)

Answer (score 2):

By doing some error tracking, you'll find that

```
TypeError: 'QasmQobj' object is not iterable`
```

was raised from

```
IBMQJobManagerInvalidStateError: Pulse schedules found, but the backend does not support pulse schedules.
```

So your code was ok, it's just that the IBMQ Bogota backend doesn't support pulse schedules. Right now it appears that the only IBMQ QPU that does support pulse schedules is IBMQ Armonk:

```
>>> provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')
>>> for backend in provider.backends():
... config = backend.configuration()
... if config.open_pulse:
...     print(config.backend_name)
ibmq_armonk
```

IBMQ Armonk is a single-qubit device, so the `qubit_lists` and any other qubit-related parts of your code will have to be modified.

Good luck!